# I've just installed (g)Vim, how do I get arrow keys to access command history?

Tags: command-line

So the problem is that I've installed (g)Vim and the arrow keys are moving around rather than going through command history.

It's a little complicated by the fact that there was an old version of vim installed by a different user (I've just inherited someone else's dev machine at a new job).  I'm running on windows and have just deleted the vimrc under program files.

What setting has changed this behaviour and how do I change it back to normal mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a `.vimrc` vim will run in cp-mode (compatibility-mode).
Just create a `.vimrc` in your home-dir and the problem should be fixed.
The `.vimrc` can be empty, though it is advisable to put `set nocp` in there.

The full story can be found in `:help 'cp`

Comment: I disagree that it's advisable to put `set nocompatible` in your otherwise empty `.vimrc`. What's your reasoning for suggesting it?

Comment: I suggested it to avoid surprises.
Simple example : `vim -u ~/.vimrc` will not automatically set nocp.

Comment: How many times have you loaded your vimrc via that command line option? How many people do you think would load their vimrc in that way *and* also be unaware that doing so would not cause `compatible` to be automatically unset? Are you aware of the additional surprises that adding that line in can cause if the vimrc is sourced from an existing session? If so, don't you think those surprises are worth mentioning/guarding against?

Comment: Probably true. But sourcing the vimrc from an existing session is full of surprises anyway. My real answer should hence have been *read :help cp*

Comment: actually, current Vims read defaults.vim which sets 'nocompatible' when no vimrc was read.